# How to get the Object type assign inside callback in the interceptor

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, interceptor

I have an `BaseResponse<T>`

```
public class BaseResponse<T> {
@SerializedName("status")
private int status;
@SerializedName("data")
private T data;
```

which is the reponse from `Http request`.The `<T>` can be both `object` or `list`.But if there's an `error` ,server make a mistake which return a `List` even if the `response` (if `success`) `return an object` like this.

```
{"status":116,"data":["Data is invalid"]}
```

So my question : Is there anyway to get the datatype inside `Callback<BaseResponse<T>` from `Interceptor`
 so I can change the data to and String Object.
Or else,is there anyway to solve my problem?

Comment: You can just call for `ResponseBody` instead.. and `deserialize` accordingly

Comment: thanks @SantanuSur, the problem is if the request is an object, the error will return as data : "abc" and if is the list, error must return [abcd] so it not jump to onFailure

Comment: it **wont** jump to `failure` if u call for `ResponseBody` even if the data in the model changes

Comment: yes,but how can i know which one to migrate to a **List<>** if the request need a List or a **Object** if it need a object

Comment: if `deserialization` with `object` fails, then try `deserialzing` with `list` in `catch()` block !

Comment: could u provide a short code? @SantanuSur

Comment: just the idea,not whole code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206054/discussion-between-shadow-and-santanu-sur).